# unable to load json data into Oracle_db

Tags: python, pyspark

```
    json_list = {"name": "Alice", "age": 25}, {"name": "Bob", "age": 30}, {"name": "Charlie", "age": 35}
    # json_list = json_data
    df = spark.createDataFrame(json_list)
    # df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(json_list))
    df.printSchema()
    df.write.format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", jdbc_url) \
        .option("dbtable", "asadsa") \
        .option("user", username) \
        .option("password", password) \
        .mode("overwrite") \
       .save()
```

**If I add this code to my python project that uses PySpark to load JSON data into the database, I get the following error.

Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.*

Comment: I'm not a Windows user but on the console, what do you get for `python --version`?

Comment: i have checked i am able to see the version of python as you told with following command python --version

Comment: More ideas: Is python on the system PATH? Is it the python version for the PySpark version? have you tried to reinstall python? [Python Path on Windows](https://geek-university.com/add-python-to-the-windows-path/)